# resourceName missing in response of Google chat media upload method

Tags: google-api, google-chat

I'm using the media.upload method for uploading files in google chat.
The documentation for the same is here [links to google chat upload method docs](https://developers.google.com/chat/api/reference/rest/v1/media/upload)

According to google document response should be of following format.

```
{
  "resourceName": string,
  "attachmentUploadToken": string
}
```

But I'm getting a response with only attachmentUploadToken and **resourceName** is missing in the response.

resourceName is a required parameter for downloading the file.

Api that I used

```
https://chat.googleapis.com/upload/v1/spaces/AAA3232AOpMBxTI/attachments:upload?filename=img.png
```

[image]

Wanted to check if there is an issue with my use of api or is this a bug from the api's end.